# AngularJS / ui-bootstrap.modal: Obtain directive element's dimensions after modal open

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm **slowly** getting the hang of AngularJS - but struggling!

I have got some working **directives** for figures drawn using *d3.js*. I am trying to implement a "pop-out in a fullscreen modal / lightbox" feature, using [ui.bootstrap.modal](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).

To draw the figures, the directive functions need to know the width and height of the final element, which I have taken from the width and height from the directive's parent element (as the directive element itself seems to not have dimensions as expected), e.g.

```
<figure id="parent"> <!-- parent has a defined width & height -->
    <figure2></figure2> <!-- my directive -->
    <figcaption>Caption goes here!</figcaption>
</figure>
```

But of course, when it's in a modal, the directive's parent element doesn't have a width & height until it's open and visible, after the directive's link function gets fired.

I've tried to put a `$watch` on the parent element's width and height (based on [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726313/when-do-we-know-the-actual-width-of-an-element-in-angular)), but it's not working for me - I guess the link function is only fired once. (NB: My knowledge of how watch functions work is limited to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/angularjs-using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply) - but I think this is where the solution might lie!)

Or should I be doing something based on the modal's `opened` or `rendered` promises? If so, where? It can't be in the directive (as the directive also exists outside the modal).

What is the best way to do this? Here's two Plunkers:

- [One which draws the figures using a constant height & width](http://plnkr.co/edit/ajWja1CYSu0CnMMGGMJ9?p=preview)
- [One where I've tried to implement the $watch.](http://plnkr.co/edit/1nSOK6MTMvbzHtwFjCy6?p=preview)

(NB: Figure 1 doesn't need the width / height, but Figure 2 does)

Thanks in advance!

Bonus questions (to save me coming back later!):

- Is there an easy way to re-draw the figures on a window-resize event?
- Is there an easy way to have a single `figure-modal.html` template which dynamically populates itself with the correct directive (`<figure1></figure1>` or `<figure2></figure2>`) based on a provided variable / expression?

Answer (score 0):

Having gone back to this problem after some time away (learning how to do Angular!), I have found a solution loosely based on another answer (which I have since lost).

The trick is to set up two watches:

```
scope.$watch (function () {
  if (element.width() !== scope.dims.width || element.height() !== scope.dims.height) {
    scope.dims = {'width': element.width(), 'height': element.height()};
  }
});

scope.$watch ('dims', function (newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal === oldVal) return;
  alert('dimensions changed');
  draw();  // Call to function to redraw the graph
});
```

The first `$watch` updates the `scope.dims` object on each digest cycle. The second $watch fires when it is updated.

May not be the best code, but it works!

For future readers - let me know if you need to see a working Plunkr.