# Directive for window resize not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a custom directive in AngularJS. The code is as follows:

```
var esscom = angular.module('esscom',['ngMaterial' ,'ngMessages','ui.bootstrap','ui.router']);


esscom.directive('resize',[function($window){
    return function($scope){
        console.log("Inside resize dir");
        angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
            console.log("Window resize");
            if( $window.innerWidth <= 960){
                console.log("Returning ess background");
                angular.element("#view").addClass('essbackground');
            }
            $scope.$apply();
        })
    };
}]);
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div resize id="view">
    <h1>Resize this</h1>
</div>
```

This just doesn't work. The resize event is never detected. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directive function should return like the following:

```
esscom.directive('resize',['$window',function($window){
    return {
        link:function($scope){
            console.log("Inside resize dir");
            angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
                console.log("Window resize");
                if( $window.innerWidth <= 960){
                    console.log("Returning ess background");
                    angular.element("#view").addClass('essbackground');
                }
                $scope.$apply();
            })
        }
    };
}]);
```

You need to inject `$window`.

Comment: I referred this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044338/window-resize-directive. This made me construct the directive the way I have typed in the question, although I know it should return an object. But your syntax also doesn't work. I have tried it.

Comment: If I am not wrong, the `resize` event will be triggered by browser window resize

Comment: Oh you forgot to inject `$window`. See my updated answer.