# Wrapping Formstone Wallpaper jquery plugin in an AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, jquery-plugins, angularjs-directive

Trying hard to implement the [Formstone Wallpaper](http://formstone.it/components/Wallpaper) JQuery plugin into my AngularJS application. I followed the instructions on the site just to learn that AngularJS and JQuery don't work well together. In many articles in the net it was mentioned that I had to wrap jquery plugins in AngularJS directives to use it the right way. I found this tutorial by [David Boike](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nz8lAKHBgJY) on how to warp the Knob jquery plugin into an AngularJS directive.

I tried to follow along and achieve that for the Formstone Wallpaper plugin. This is my attempt:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app').directive('formstoneWallpaper',[function() {
    return {
            restrict: 'E',
            link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                    elem.wallpaper({
                            source: {
                                    poster: attrs.poster,
                                    mp4: attrs.mp4,
                                    ogg: attrs.ogg,
                                    webm: attrs.webm
                            }
                    });
            }
    };
}]);
```

Then my html markup changes to:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row wall">

        <formstone-wallpaper
            poster="modules/launch/videos/ocean.jpg"
            mp4="modules/launch/videos/ocean.mp4"
            ogg="modules/launch/videos/ocean.ogv"
            webm="modules/launch/videos/ocean.webm"
        ></formstone-wallpaper>

    </div><!--row-->
</div><!--container-->
```

Yet this does not result in the desired full-width responsive video wallpaper. Instead the `width` and `height` is somehow set to 0px. I therefore do not see anything on my website. However, when I kill the `wallpaper-container` and `wallpaper-media` classes, the problem is partially resolved in that the video finally appears (however, it is not responsive and fittet to screen size-the reason why we are doing this exercise in the first place). Here is a screenshot from my chrome inspector.[image: chrome]

Can someone help me to improve the code for the directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

friends, it turned out the above directive is actually alright. The real problem that I had was my lack of understanding of nested relative positioning. I used [this "resize" directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703517/angular-js-set-element-height-on-page-load) to dynamically set the height of my container to the height of the viewport.

This is the css that finally fixes the my issue:

```
formstone-wallpaper {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: auto;
        height: auto;
        padding: 100px 0;
        min-height: 100%;
        background: no-repeat center center;
        background-attachment: scroll;
        background-size: cover;
}
```

Set the "resize" attribute on your container like so:

```
<div class="container-fluid" data-ng-style="style()" resize>
    <div class="row">

        <formstone-wallpaper
            poster="modules/launch/videos/ocean.jpg"
            mp4="modules/launch/videos/ocean.mp4"
            ogg="modules/launch/videos/ocean.ogv"
            webm="modules/launch/videos/ocean.webm"
        ></formstone-wallpaper>

    </div><!--row-->
</div><!--container-->
```

Comment: Maybe someone has a better way of doing this in which case I will be accepting your answer. If not, 3 months from now, I'll be accepting this one.